# Intermittently lose Intellisense for Razor pages

Tags: visual-studio-2010, razor, resharper, intellisense

I've seen a lot of different posts on this, most of them outdated.  I'm running VS2010 SP1 Release version, ReSharper 5.1.3.12, and the release version of MVC 3.  All the fixes that are supposed to solve this problem are in place.

Sometimes I have Intellisense on Razor pages, and sometimes I don't. Sometimes if I close a file and re-open it, it will give me Intellisense back, sometimes it won't.  It's driving me bananas.

I read the JetBrains blog, and tried pressing Cntl-Space after typing "@Html.", and it gave me a list of HTML options (as though it were in an HTML editor).  But the editor for cshtml pages is the Razor editor.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Dave, try the Resharper 6 Beta (http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/tag/resharper-6/) - its quite stable now and may address this issue (plus has an improved razor editor)